# Rails : date_select validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am modifying a `text_field` to a `date_select` in a form on my company website. I'm new to RoR and I have an error saying that `born_on` cannot be empty.
Here is the new code

```
<div class="lobbyForm-group">
    <%= f.label :born_on, class: 'lobbyForm-label' %>
    <%= f.date_select 'user', :born_on, {:order => [:day, :month, :year], :start_year => 2001, :end_year => 1985, :prompt => true, :selected => Date.today}, {:class => "lobbyForm-control lobbyForm-control-selectDate"}  %>
</div>
```

It is validated by this line in my user.rb

```
  validates :born_on, presence: true, if: :mentee?
```

And I have this output in the log when I click validate :

```
"born_on(3i)"=>"3", "born_on(2i)"=>"12", "born_on(1i)"=>"2001"
```

Here is the related code in the controller :

```
protected
  def after_sign_up_path
    new_lobby_mentee_registrations_profile_path
  end
  def user_params
    permitted_params = [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :born_on, :marketing_communications_accepted]
    params.require(:user).permit(*permitted_params)

    params[:user].merge mentee: true
  end
  def ensure_required_user_information
    if current_user.profile.blank?
      redirect_to new_lobby_mentee_registrations_profile_path
    end
  end
end
```

What am I missing ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you put your related code in `controller` so that I can help you? And please double check the filed name in your database, is it `birth_date` or `born_on`?

Comment: The filed name in my db is born_on my mistake for changing it in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the date `hash` to a `Date` type yourself in `user_params` method like this:

```
date = Date.new params[:user]["born_on(1i)"].to_i, params[:user]["born_on(2i)"].to_i, params[:user]["born_on(3i)"].to_i 
params[:user][:born_on] = date

permitted_params = [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :born_on, :marketing_communications_accepted]
params.require(:user).permit(*permitted_params)

params[:user].merge mentee: true
```

Comment: The controller does not recognize user["born_on(1i)"], I have this error : undefined local variable or method `user' for #<Lobby::MenteeRegistrationsController

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Updated the answer.